# cant update array contents java

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ElectionStatistics {

  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String[] party = {"a","b","c"};
      String p;
      float v;
      float[] pVotes = {1,2,3};
      float totalVotes = 0;

      for(int i = 0; i>3; i++)
      {
        p = input.nextLine();
        party[i] = p;
        v= input.nextFloat();
        pVotes[i] = v;
        totalVotes = totalVotes = v;

        System.out.println(totalVotes);
      }

      for (int y = 0; y < party.length; y++) 
      {
        System.out.println(party[y] + " received: " + pVotes[y]/totalVotes + "%");
      }
      
      

   }
}
```

neither array is updating with the inputs

the output of the program is

```
a received: Infinity%
b received: Infinity%
c received: Infinity%
```

Comment: check `for(int i = 0; i>3; i++)` - the condition - 2nd expression, that it `i>3` - must be true for the loop to iterate, it is **not** the condition for it to terminate - as soon as it is `false` the loop will terminate, even before the first iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first loop seems false. Because i>3 always false. This should be true. Additionally, there seems to be an error in the calculation of totalVotes. In each iteration of the loop, totalVotes is only adding the last read vote, but it should be calculating the total votes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] party = {"a","b","c"};
        String p;
        float v;
        float[] pVotes = {1,2,3};
        float totalVotes = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            p = input.nextLine();
            party[i] = p;
            v = input.nextFloat();
            input.nextLine(); //You can research Token Based Input and Line Based Input
            pVotes[i] = v;
            totalVotes += v;
        }

        if (totalVotes == 0) {
            System.out.println("Handle Divided By Zero");
        } else {
            for (int y = 0; y < party.length; y++) {
                System.out.println(party[y] + " received: " + (pVotes[y] / totalVotes) * 100 + "%");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. but can you explain why the input.nextLine(); is needed i don't really understand, how is it taking an input when none is being entered.  I'm still kind new to java

Comment: For this topic you should many spend time. As i say in my code, you can research Token Based Input and Line Based Input